# How to automatically find or add the latest sheet added to an specific folder location

Tags: javascript, csv, google-sheets

I need help with my google sheets report with two things. I will explain.

I have my google sheet script that send data from a csv file to a google sheet file making a report and so far works great have no issues. but the only problem is that daily I have to manually add the new cvs file name so my scripts grabs that csv data and send the data to a new google sheet for report purposes from a trigger daily at 9am. so I want to see if there is a way so instead of me adding manually the new csv name the script can find it and add it.

so here I have to manually add the new csv file name manually before my triggers runs, I want to see if instead of my adding it the script can do it for me.

var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('201707230600060843.csv'); // latest report file

here is the daily trigger I need to run everyday
[image]

Here is my script

```
function importData() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById("0ByXeCX01JfKJN1dTNk1SRlQyb1k"); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('201707230600060843.csv'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1T2JU4KwpJsnlJk0LOEZoHr9uqnNrVYwBWI1NxOwL4PU"); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data


  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "report.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    //var newsheet = ss.insertSheet("NEWDATA"); // create a 'NEWDATA' sheet to store imported data
    var sheetname = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetname);
    // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'NEWDATA' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      newsheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
    /*
    ** report data is now in 'NEWDATA' sheet in the spreadsheet - process it as needed,
    ** then delete 'NEWDATA' sheet using ss.deleteSheet(newsheet)
    */                                                    
    // rename the report.csv file so it is not processed on next scheduled run
    file.setName("report-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set it up so that it doesn't matter what the new file name is as long as it has the extension .csv. At the end I change the extension to old for all files so that they won't be reprocessed the next day.

```
function importData(folderID)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1T2JU4KwpJsnlJk0LOEZoHr9uqnNrVYwBWI1NxOwL4PU");
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : '0ByXeCX01JfKJN1dTNk1SRlQyb1k';//default folderID
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = fldr.getFiles();
  var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd");
  var re =new RegExp('^' + dt + '.*\.csv$','i');
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    if(filename.match(re))
    {
      var csvstr=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var csvA=Utilities.parseCsv(csvstr);
      var sheetname = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/dd/yyyy'-'HH:mm:ss");
      var newsheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetname); 
      newsheet.getRange(1, 1, csvA.length, csvA[0].length).setValues(csvA);
      file.setName(filename.slice(0,-3) + 'old');  //the .old files won't pass the file re filter next time. 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will run your script tomorrow morning at 9am to see if it works, I will let you know. but thanks for all I will get back to you tomorrow with the results, thanks.

Comment: keep in mind it will process all files with .csv extension.  You may want to either remove them or change their extension to .old.

Comment: I tested it and yes it works but the only problem is that is grabbing all the cvs files, I think I liked the way you did it before where you had it grabbing by the file name current date since each cvs is added to the folder is always show the current date for example 201707260600060843.csv which is today then will only grab that one and exclude the other ones, can you add that to your script? because I don't to manually remove the csv files because daily I sent cvs files to the same folder

Comment: After checking your script better, that should fix my issue. Thanks man.

Comment: Okay. I added the new RegExp() function so I could inject the current date programmatically.  I haven't tested it so let me know if your having problems.  Again, it will take any csv that begins with the current date in this format: "yyyyMMdd".

Comment: Thanks again man, I will try that today and get back to you after testing the new script.

Comment: After multiple testing all works thanks man, but there is an issue looks like of the folder variable when I do the schedule trigger daily I am getting this notification error after the trigger fails daily: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 5, file "Code") and referecing to this   var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : '0ByXeCX01JfKJN1dTNk1SRlQyb1k';//default folderID
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

Comment: I got that folder ID from your code here's the comment next to it: `// reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved` it's in the seccond line of your code `var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById("0ByXeCX01JfKJN1dTNk1SRlQyb1k");`

Comment: that is correct and that is the correct folder ID i need is where all the files are, but why is giving me that error for the daily triggers, but when  I run it manually it works and puts it in the sheet, is the daily trigger is the issue what could be causing this

Comment: Can I see your trigger function?

Comment: I added the daily trigger I run daily to my first post above please check

Comment: I don't know.  Try posting it as a new question.  Perhaps someone else can figure it out.

Comment: I will do that, thanks for all your help your new script works nice, just need to fix the trigger issue

Comment: I'm sure someone will figure it out. But I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work since it has a default folderID defined.  But perhaps trigger functions may not accept functions with parameters.  You might try taking out the parameter and just say `var folderID='0ByXeCX01JfKJN1dTNk1SRlQyb1k';`

Comment: I will do that before I submit another question

Comment: so now it worked, after removing the parameter from the function and making the variable var folderID='0ByXeCX01JfKJN1dTNk1SRlQyb1k' fixed the issue, thanks man for all the help.